# $z= \frac{u-\overline{u}v}{1-v}$ is real is equivalent to $|v|=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $u,v$ be complex numbers such as $u,v\notin \mathbb{R} $, and :
$$z= \frac{u-\overline{u}v}{1-v}$$

Prove that : $z\in\mathbb{R} \Longleftrightarrow |v|=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$|v|=1\Longleftrightarrow |v|^2=1\Longleftrightarrow v \bar{v}=1 \Longleftrightarrow \bar{v}=\frac{1}{v} \Longleftrightarrow \bar{z}=$$

$$\dfrac{\bar{u}-u \dfrac{1}{v}}{1-\dfrac{1}{v}} \Longleftrightarrow \bar{z}=\dfrac{\bar{u} v-u}{v-1} \Longleftrightarrow \bar{z}=z \Longleftrightarrow z \in \mathbb R$$

Comment: @Gigili it looks more uglier now.

Comment: Nice, smooth and short. +1

Comment: @Kaster: I didn't ask for your opinion.

Comment: @Gigili well, you should have, or you correct posts just for yourself?

Comment: @Kaster: For Michael specifically in this case, and everyone else except you.

Comment: @Gigili is it why there is a new correction over yours? :) which is much more prettier, btw.

Comment: @Kaster: No, that's because we're a great community and we try to help each other. And more importantly, we appreciate each other's help.